Does anyone understand why my code is not reading the hi.txt code it says it is in the wrong directory which confuses me as it is in the same folder
[enter image Folderhere](https://i.sstatic.net/xF2AnS6i.png)
[Code[Codeenter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/TZuiYqJj.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/YfEHPKx7.png)
I am having trouble for the txt file to be read using my python code saying that it is in the wrong directory, which they are in the same folder so I am very confused what the solution is for this issue.

Put code as text, not an image

When you use open(), it looks for the file relative to the current working directory. When a Python script is running, the current working directory is where you called the program from. (So this code would work if you executed it from C:/Users/babak/OneDrive/hi)
To address this issue, you could just use an absolute path
filename = 'C:/Users/babak/OneDrive/hi/hi.txt'

Alternatively, you could get the directory of the script file (dan.py) and construct a relative path:
filename = 'hi.txt'
...

# recommended modern way to deal with paths
import pathlib
with open(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / filename) as f:
    ...

# traditional "os" method; if using Python 2
import os
with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), filename)) as f:
    ...


os.path is a little bit outdated if you compare it with pathlib. With pathlib you get with open(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / filename) as f:.
